# ViewModel remains null or without values after jQuery Ajax post

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC form set up like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm"}))
{
    @Html.Partial("_Action", Model)
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="createButton" class="btn btn-primary">@Resources.Global.CreateActionButton</button>
    </div>
}
```

Here's the code of the partial:

```
@model EWI_JOPWeb.Models.ActionsViewModel
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Action.Id)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Action.Number)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Action.Number, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", placeholder = "Vul hier een nummer in" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Action.Title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Action.Title, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Vul hier tekst in" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Action.DepartmentNumber)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Action.DepartmentNumber, Model.DepartmentSelectItems, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker noBoxShadow", title = "Selecteer opties...", data_selected_text_format = "count > 0", multiple = "multiple" })
</div>

<!-- Other similar controls -->
```

Following code is used to submit to a controller:

```
$("#createButton").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateAction", "Home")?spHostUrl=' + getSPHostUrlFromQueryString(window.location.search),
        dataType: "json",
        data: { viewModel: $("#createForm").serialize() },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            //show successMessage
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            //show errorMessage
        }
    });
});
```

And of course the controller/viewmodel code:

```
[HttpPost]
[SharePointContextFilter]
public ActionResult CreateAction(ActionsViewModel viewModel)
{
    //process 'viewModel'
}

public class ActionsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<DepartmentViewModel> Departments { get; set; }
    public Action Action { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeSelectItems => new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Beheersactie", Text = @"Beheersactie", Selected = true },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Beleidsactie", Text = @"Beleidsactie", Selected = false }
    };

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentSelectItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PolicyDocumentSelectItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BudgetArticleSelectItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonitoringSelectItems { get; set; }
}
```

The result of `$("#createForm").serialize()` is similar to:

> __RequestVerificationToken=D71hJi2rti_r2nyqi5KLg1iYnUHIMoVizjoR5ru2fsVa4CAhRTr-3dqi9bzdWZGlE2fNZReSIzySm_B2gtmbubPWaIchekaTmOdyerwahD01&Action.Id=&Action.Number=23&Action.Title=test&Action.DepartmentNumber=f4663eb2-e9b1-4aea-a7e9-b1b49eb100a7

But when the debugger hits the controller method, `viewModel` remains *null*.

I have searched and tried solutions from following other questions:

- [How to post the viewmodel to action method using JQUERY AJAX in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105072/how-to-post-the-viewmodel-to-action-method-using-jquery-ajax-in-mvc)
- [MVC3 Passing ViewModel to controller method using JQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871365/mvc3-passing-viewmodel-to-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax)
- ["Invalid JSON primitive" in Ajax processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445874/invalid-json-primitive-in-ajax-processing)
- [How to serialize model, pass it to MVC controller in ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944495/how-to-serialize-model-pass-it-to-mvc-controller-in-ajax-request)

But none of these solutions have worked for me.

Now I changed my code and added variables for the selected items and such:

```
public string SelectedType { get; set; }
public List<string> SelectedDepartment { get; set; }
public List<string> SelectedPolicyDocuments { get; set; }
public List<string> SelectedBudgetArticles { get; set; }
public List<string> SelectedMonitorings { get; set; }
```

And in my markup I adjusted this to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMonitorings,
                      new MultiSelectList(Model.MonitoringSelectItems, "Id", "Title", Model.SelectedMonitorings),
                      new { @class = "form-control selectpicker noBoxShadow",
                      title = "Selecteer opties...",
                      data_selected_text_format = "count > 0",
                      multiple = "multiple" })
```

The viewmodel is not *null* anymore but on the other hand, the selected values are not coming through. If I select one or more items from the MultiSelect, the SelectedXXX list has always 1 item with no value.

Does anyone have any idea what is the correct way to reconstruct the ViewModel from a jQuery AJAX call to the Controller method? I am kind of list because there are several ways and combinations to achieve this.

Comment: Note: You do not have to serialise the form to the named `viewModel` parameter. MVC will map the values to the model with just `data: $("#createForm").serialize() `

Comment: Also dropdown lists are very buggy in MVC. The only variations we use now is the @Html.DropDownList("FieldName") version with the lookups in a ViewBag entry of the same name.

Comment: @GoneCoding when I don't serialize it to the name, the SelectedXXX lists are filled but the Action in my ViewModel remains *null*.

Comment: Are you newing your Action property in the constructor of Viewmodel? It will usually only map to properties and not create child objects. Same goes for any incoming lists.

Comment: What do you mean *newing*? So you mean when I post, no new `Action` object is created to put in the ViewModel?

Comment: Correct. In your viewmodel constructor (which I can't see) you need to create any incoming lists or child objects that are not simple value properties. I should have said `new`ing as in `Action = new Action()` :)

Comment: I added `public ActionsViewModel() { Action = new Action(); }` to my ViewModel class but it remains *null*... Only if I create a ViewModel with all 'flat' properties, they get filled again.

Comment: Its just `data: $("#createForm").serialize(),`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke as I stated in the comments: when I use that, the ViewModel won't be *null* anymore but the *Action* property still is.

Comment: The `Action` property will NOT be `null` based on the code you have shown. If it is, then its due to code you have not shown (and as a side note, use `ListBoxFor(m => m.Action.DepartmentNumber, ...)`, not `DropDownListFor() with the `multiple` attribute - there are reasons that usage will fail)